# Angular using ng-model in input field get null

Tags: javascript, angularjs, null, angular-ngmodel, ngmodel

I know how to pass a  value from a view to a controller using `ng-model`. In the controller it just gets the value from the view using this code `$scope.name = this.ngmodelnameinview`.

Is it compulsory to use `ng-model` in field view?

but my problem now is, I have `+` button, which when I click the button it will automatically put the value inside input text field.

```
<button data-ng-click="adultCount = adultCount+1"> + </button>
<input type="text" name="totTicket" value="{{adultCount}}">
```

see picture below:[image]

but when I add `ng-model` inside input field, it returns `null`

```
<input type="text" name="totTicket" value="{{adultCount}}" ng-model="adultcount">
```

How to fix this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It is giving null just because you have set a value "adultCount" and in ng-model you had given a different name "adultcount" ('c' is in lower case). By updating ng-model with "adultCount", will solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript is case sensitive:

> JavaScript is case-sensitive and uses the Unicode character set.<sup>[1](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Grammar_and_types)</sup>

Use the same case for the scope variable. Update the input attribute `ng-model` to match the varible - i.e.:

```
<input type="text" name="totTicket" value="{{adultCount}}" ng-model="adultcount">
```

should be:

```
<input type="text" name="totTicket" value="{{adultCount}}" ng-model="adultCount">
<!--                                                                      ^   -->
```

See this demonstrated in the snippet below:

```js
angular.module('app', [])
.controller('ctrl', function($scope) {
     //adultCount could be initialized here
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
<button data-ng-click="adultCount = adultCount+1"> + </button>
totTicket:
<input type="text" name="totTicket" value="{{adultCount}}">
totTicket (adultCount):
<input type="text" name="totTicket" value="{{adultCount}}" ng-model="adultCount">
</div>
```

——

<sup>1</sup><sub>https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Grammar_and_types</sub>